# How to arrange Endpoints and Categories in Swagger-jsdoc?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-jsdocs

Is there a way to arrange API Categories and Endpoints in Swagger?
I'm using **swagger-jsdoc** and **swagger-ui** modules with Node.js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is tags: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please understand that linked content is not considered part of an answer here on StackOverflow. So your post shrivels to "use tags". You might want to add something, e.g. example code.